# Digital Logic Basics - Creating simply lock mechanism

Tags: digital-logic

I'm not sure where else I can ask a question like this, I've been searching around and can't seem to find a proper place to ask about basic digital logic.
I'm doing a computer science course and have been practising basic circuit designs online.

I've been given a problem where I have to make simple key and lock mechanism where I have three lock inputs and three key inputs and if the key input matches the lock an LED will light up. It says I can only use AND NOT and OR gates and to use a decoder.

I've made a start but it's probably far from right:

[image]

Would I need to use a 3-8 decoder? I'm not sure how this can be done, would like any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways of going about this.  One of these is to use XNOR (exclusive NOR) gates, which have a truth table like this:

[image]

So the output is 1 if the inputs match.  Call the three inputs of the lock L0, L1, and L2, and the key K0, K1 and K2.  The lock is opened (LED on) if

```
(L0 XNOR K0) AND (L1 XNOR K1) AND (L2 XNOR K2)
```

is true.  You can build a XNOR gate from AND's, OR's, and NOT's like this:

[image]

But this doesn't use the 3 to 8 decoder.  To make use of that, you could decode the three lock inputs into eight decoded lock outputs LD0 ... LD7, and same for the key inputs to KD0 ... KD7.  Then AND LD0 and KD0 together, all the way to LD7 AND KD7, OR the outputs of the AND's together and that is your output.

You built the decode part of the 3 to 8 decode correctly at the bottom of your figure, up to and including the AND's, just get rid of the OR gates.  I'm not sure what you were trying to do at the top of your diagram.

Comment: @fark Yes, the two decoder solution was what I was trying to describe at the bottom of my answer.   The case of the LED lighting up with everything 0's is okay -- both the lock and the key are 0 0 0, so they match.  Nothing to fix.

Comment: My bad, I did read that wrong you were right. Are you able to point me in the direction if I wanted to lock the circuit after N amount of attempts? E.g. having more inputs X1, X2, X3 equal to n http://i.imgur.com/PKuN4Qg.png

Comment: @fark That's something that would require a new question.